# problem in nsuserdefaults

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

hii every one i have stil problem in nsuser defaults i'll tell the scenerio in detail

1. First i have diclared nsmutable array in appDelegate and set it in NSUserDefaults With    For Key@"abc"
2. In FirstView Controller i first fetch the array from NSUserDefaults and save its values in NSMutable Array
3. When a Click say abcButton i have create a dictionary and adding values in it like

   ```
   [abcDictionar setObject:[[abcMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"abc"]             forKey:@"abc"];
   ```
4. When i added all values in NSDictionary Then i add NSDictionary in NSMutable Array 
   like This

   ```
   [abcMutableArray addObject:abcDictionary];
   ```
5. Then i save it NSUserDefaults 
   It Give me Exception in Point 4
6. When i add nsdictionary in Point One It All work fine but data in array is ambigous and it raise exception when am going to display it in tableview

if any one has some idea then let me know thanks in advance...:)

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting?

Comment: `NSMutableArray*abcJobMutableArray=[[NSMutableArrayalloc]init];
[prefs setObject:abcJobMutableArray forKey:@"abcJobMutableArray"];
in .m AppDelegatre `

Comment: `in abcClass.m file i'll write this code NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  xyzMutableArray = (NSMutableArray *)[prefs objectForKey:@"abcJobMutableArray"];          [abcJobDictionary setObject:[[abcListMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"xyz"] forKey:@"abc"];
 
 [favouriteJobsMutableArray addObject:favouriteJobDictionary];
 `

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` does not store mutable objects, only immutable ones. When you retrieve objects from it you must cast/copy them into mutable objects if you wish to mutate them.

Also be aware that:

> The `NSUserDefaults` class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of `NSData`.

Which is from the [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.